# Why is my tableview getting an error when im using this code firebase Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

hey i have 2 tableviews one on the `mainpage` one on `userprofilepage` the one on the `mainpage` is to show the public all the posts that exist but the one on the `profilepage` is the same but i want to change it to so only that user that is currently online on that user uid's posts is shown in the `profilepage` tableview

i am currently using this code and it is this code that shows me every single post instead of only the ones that only `ThatUser` has uploaded but this code does not give me error´s

```
func loadTableViewData(){

        if ((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) != nil) {
            Database.database().reference().child("userposts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for userPost in postsDictionary {
                        self.userPosts.add(userPost.value)

                    }
                    self.userPostsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but then i change it to this code because i'm saving the post to the user's uid aswell as shown in the database image but this one does not give me error but i when i open the app and the go to the `userprofilepage` the app crashes

```
 if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            Database.database().reference().child("userposts").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    for userPost in postsDictionary {
                        self.userPosts.add(userPost.value)

                    }
                    self.userPostsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and i get this error in the console

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1043fcf68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1043fdf58).
>   2017-11-23 14:17:30.616973+0100 Acty10[21308:164951] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1043fcf68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1043fdf58).
>   (lldb)

iam pretty sure this code should generaly work but maybe i'm doing something wrong

Here is a image of my database

[image]

as you can se iam using the uid inside of userposts then iam trying to retrive it the same way but i get that crash please help me someone.

here is the `cellForRowAt` code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableViewCell
     // Configure the cell...
        let userPost = self.userPosts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        cell.profileTitleLabel.text = userPost["title"] as? String
        cell.profileContentView.text = userPost["content"] as? String
        cell.profileTimeAndDateLabel.text = userPost["time"] as? String
        cell.profileUsernameLabel.text = userPost["username"] as? String
        cell.profileLocationAddress.text = userPost["adress"] as? String

        if let imageName = userPost["image"] as? String {

            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    //successfull
                    let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.profileImageView.image = downloadedImage
                }else {
                    // error

                    print("there was an error downloading image: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
}
```

thanks for your time :)

Comment: Add cell for row code

Comment: there it is @jigneshVadadoriya

Comment: crash heppens at this line??

 let userPost = self.userPosts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]

Comment: which line crash occur?

Comment: The error message says that you are casting an object to **dictionary** but actually it's a **string**. Is there an item in `userPosts` which is not a dictionary?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya yes exacty thats the line

Comment: @vadian nope everything in there is in the dictonary as you can see on the image

Comment: I can see only one item in the screenshot. Then the error occurs somewhere else. The error message is distinct.

Comment: I Know i also think this code should actually work @vadian

Comment: Set breakpoint(s) and debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid crash

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    if let userPost = self.userPosts[indexPath.row] as? [String: AnyObject] {

        cell.profileTitleLabel.text = userPost["title"] as? String
        cell.profileContentView.text = userPost["content"] as? String
        cell.profileTimeAndDateLabel.text = userPost["time"] as? String
        cell.profileUsernameLabel.text = userPost["username"] as? String
        cell.profileLocationAddress.text = userPost["adress"] as? String

        if let imageName = userPost["image"] as? String {

            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    //successfull
                    let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.profileImageView.image = downloadedImage
                }else {
                    // error

                    print("there was an error downloading image: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: @Jiyar checkout my answer

Comment: tryed this now but it didnt work it duplicated both post 3 times so it was 6 posts in total and nothing from the database was retrived

Comment: atleast i didnt get the error but it got worse hahah